# UITableView.ScrollToTop - Change what it considers the "top"

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'd like to be able to specify the offset or more specifically the cell I consider the "top" of my UITableView when the status bar is pressed and the ScrollToTop occurs.

To give this question a bit of context, its an app that plays music and the table view is the playlist. I'd like that when the user taps the status bar, it scrolls back to the current song, rather than continues scrolling past it into the previously played, grayed out songs. Whilst I agree which not changing default behavior, I think that this would be the expected behavior for a user in this scenario, and several people i've asked agree with me. As to whether its possible is a different story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify the position directly, but you can implement the [`scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewShouldScrollToTop%3a) delegate method to manually scroll to the appropriate position and then return `NO` to prevent the default behaviour.

Comment: Haven't got a chance to test it, but pretty sure this is on the money. Thanks.

Comment: Tested and working.  The only issue is if you're at the top of the list then `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` doesn't get called.  Which kinda makes sense.